# How do I wrap up a series of related NSTask operations into discrete functions

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstask

I'm writing a *Swift* command line tool that uses `NSTask` to interact with `git`. In the simplest scenario I want to run three commands: `init`, `add .`, and `commit -m Initial Commit`. I intend to use a separate `NSTask` for each command, and want to house each command in its own function - returning `true` if the task succeeded or `false` if it didn't. This set-up would allow my `main` function to look like this:

```
func main() {

    if runInit() {
        if runStage() {
            if runCommit() {
                 NSLog("success!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To accomplish this each of the three functions must do the following before returning (i) launch the task (ii) wait for it to complete, (iii) obtain whatever is in `stdout`, and (iv) set the return value (`true` or `false`). Here's what I've got for the commit stage:

```
func runCommit() -> Bool {

    var retval = false

    var commitTask = NSTask()
    commitTask.standardOutput = NSPipe()
    commitTask.launchPath = gitPath
    commitTask.arguments = ["commit", "-m", "Initial Commit"]
    commitTask.currentDirectoryPath = demoProjectURL.path!

    commitTask.standardOutput.fileHandleForReading.readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify()

    nc.addObserverForName(NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification,
        object: commitTask.standardOutput.fileHandleForReading,
        queue: nil) { (note) -> Void in
            // get the output, log it, then...
            if commitTask.terminationStatus == EXIT_SUCCESS {
                retval = true
            } 
    }

    commitTask.launch()
    commitTask.waitUntilExit()

    return retval

}
```

My question is essentially about how `waitUntilExit` works, particularly in conjunction with the notification I sign up for to enable me to get the output. Apple's docs say:

> This method first checks to see if the receiver is still running using isRunning. Then it polls the current run loop using NSDefaultRunLoopMode until the task completes.

I'm a bit out of my depth when it comes to run loop mechanics, and was wondering what this means in this context - can I safely assume that my notification block will **always** be executed before the enclosing function returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`waitUntilExit` returns when the `SIGCHILD` signal has been received
to indicate that the child process has terminated. The notification 
block is executed when `EOF` is read from the pipe to the child process.
It is *not* specified which of these events occurs first.

Therefore you have to wait for both. There are several possible solutions,
here is one using a "signalling semaphore", you could also use
a "dispatch group".

Another error in your code is that the observer is never removed.

```
func runCommit() -> Bool {

    let commitTask = NSTask()
    commitTask.standardOutput = NSPipe()
    commitTask.launchPath = gitPath
    commitTask.arguments = ["commit", "-m", "Initial Commit"]
    commitTask.currentDirectoryPath = demoProjectURL.path!

    commitTask.standardOutput!.fileHandleForReading.readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify()

    let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    var obs : NSObjectProtocol!
    obs = nc.addObserverForName(NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification,
        object: commitTask.standardOutput!.fileHandleForReading, queue: nil) {
            (note) -> Void in
            // Get data and log it.
            if let data = note.userInfo?[NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem] as? NSData,
                let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    print(string)
            }
            // Signal semaphore.
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
            nc.removeObserver(obs)
    }

    commitTask.launch()
    // Wait for process to terminate.
    commitTask.waitUntilExit()
    // Wait for semaphore to be signalled.
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    let retval = commitTask.terminationStatus == EXIT_SUCCESS
    return retval
}
```